# Single shared precompiled header for C++ project (multiple libraries and executables) using CMake

Tags: c++, build, cmake, shared, precompiled

I would like to know if anyone here has managed to use CMake to build a precompiled header in a single location within a project and then use it from that location to build the other libraries and executables of the project. The only way I have managed to do this is to copy the pch file manually in each library/executable folder but I want to avoid having to do this because it takes a lot of space and time.

Say I have this project structure

```
root
| include
  - precompiled.h
  - common_project_header_files
| src
  | precompiled
    - precompiled.cc
  | lib1
    - source/header files for lib1
  | lib2
    - source/header files for lib2
| lib
```

I would like to first build *precompiled.pch* using *precompiled.h* and *precompiled.cc* (which only includes *precompiled.h*) in a location visible to the libraries' files  and then use it from there to build lib1 and lib2.

Can this be done using CMake?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a working solution (albeit not perfect, see below).
Say that `precompiled` is the target of the build command that creates your `precompiled.pch` in the build directory. Add a custom command to `precompiled`, like so:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET precompiled POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
  copy  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/precompiled.pch"
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/precompiled.pch")
```

This will copy `precompiled.pch` into your `include` folder whenever it is built. However, you will still run into problems if your `lib1` and `lib2` targets are built before `precompiled`, so you have to add `precompiled` as a dependency of those two to enforce the right build order:

```
add_dependencies(lib1 precompiled)
add_dependencies(lib2 precompiled)
```

The reason that I said this is not perfect is that (at least for me) `precompiled.pch` will be rebuilt from scratch every single time `lib1` or `lib2` are built (I don't know why). If this is acceptable to you, this solution should work, though.